# Shopping cart wont let me add two products with the same ID in the database

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart system that works fine until I realised that if you add two of the same products, they both go in the cart but only one is added to the database when the user clicks purchase.

Not sure what this is to do with exactly. My code is designed so there is a logic back end with IF statements with a POST[purchase]:

```
if($_POST['purchase']) {

        foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item) {

            $sql="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty_orders VALUES (".$user_id.", ".$item['id'].", NOW())";

            if($result=mysql_query($sql)){

                $confpurchase = '?confpurchase=success&id='.$item['id'].''; //USING THE URL FOR MESSAGE PASSING... ONLY IF THE PRODUCT WAS INSERTED INTO THE DATABASE!

            }

        }

        $cart->empty_cart();

        unset($_SESSION['cart']); 

        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."/my-account".$confpurchase);
        exit;


}
```

Is it to do with something like mysql wont let two of the same rows entered into the database in one loop or something? The user ID and itemID would be the same if they added the same product more than once.

Thanks!

EDIT--------------------------------

OK ive realised my mistake, when looping through the cart contents you I am meant to pull in the itemID and the itemQTY (quantity) also. I guess this is to stop the same ID shown more than once. This still gives me the problem of not being able to enter more of the same items into the database though :/

```
foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item1) {          
    echo $item1['id']; 
    echo $item1['qty'];
```

}

For example, if there are two products with ID of 100, this with echo out 1002.

Thanks people :)

Comment: Sorry mate, ive edited my question after finding out my problem...

Comment: Was there a UNIQUE constraint on the DB for either of those fields?

Comment: No there wasnt, basically the way my cart was set up meant that if two of the same product IDs were added to the cart, it wouldnt recognise as two id's, instead it would add 1 to the quantity array. So to solve my problem I just added a for loop and looped through the query according to the $item1['qty'] value.

Comment: But in light of this, I realised that my database wasnt built in a great way because thsi meant there would be duplicate values if someone added the same product twice. Instead I should really have had a quantity field in the database (at the moment it just adds the entry twice if the user purchased 2 items).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a UNIQUE constraint on one of those fields in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your particular shopping cart works, but logically you should have a quantity column and change it to 2 etc.

EDIT
Just seen your edit. Ignore this.